# Export function and call it from a different file

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to export the below function and call it on a different file. It half-works. For example: If I call the function from the same file, it does save the data to the DB. However, If I call the function from a different file, it does not save it.

Token.js:

```
    var express = require("express");
    var router = express.Router();
    var User = require("../models/user");
    var request = require("request");

    var refresh = function() {
    request.post(
        {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "api",
            Authorization:
            "auth"
        },
        url: "token",
        form: {
            grant_type: "refresh_token",
            refresh_token:
            "token"
        }
        },
        function(error, response, body) {
        var token = JSON.parse(body);
        // res.send(token);
        User.findOneAndUpdate(
            { user: 2 },
            { token: token.access_token },
            { upsert: true },
            function(err, data) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("Saved!");
            }
        ).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
        }
    );
    };
    module.exports = refresh;
```

call.js

```
var refreshToken = require("./helpers/refresh-token");

refreshToken();
```

Edit: Fixed... I forgot to include call.js in app.js

Thank you

Comment: There's not enough data. What exactly does an app that works look like and an app that doesn't work look like? It's unclear where call.js is used, and what does it have to do with Express. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate both cases.

Comment: @estus, My apologies. I forgot to include call.js on the app.js! It's all fixed now.

Comment: Glad it was that simple. I guess the case is closed then.